# I can't install flash player

Tags: command-line, software-installation, flash

I tried every version of Flash player for Ubuntu 12.10, but it doesn't work.
When attempting to install it, I got this error.

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package flashplugin-nonfree
```

I found this solution, I ran:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

and then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

which I found from some other post that was trying to solve dependencies.

Then I ran

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-nonfree
```

But it still doesn't work!

Answer (score 3):

Open a **Terminal** with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and type:

`sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

Alternatively the following command will install all the multimedia plugins and libraries that needed to play mp3 and video formats . This command will install adobe flash player too.

`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Answer (score 1):

This is how I installed it. I dont know if you tried it but:

Go to YouTube using Firefox and it will say you don't have Flash installed and install it from the popup bubble in Firefox. That's the only way it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

If the above methods still do not work and if going to adobe doesn't work , you can always try adding the medibuntu repo or installing from the Software Center

Answer (score 0):

First download the .tar.gz version of Flash player from [Adobe](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/). Now unpack this .tar.gz file in your home directory, open terminal and type:

```
sudo cp libflashlayer.so BrowserPluginLocation
```

Now copy the Flash Player Local Settings configurations files to the /usr directory by typing :

```
sudo cp -r usr/* /usr
```

**NOTE:** In my case BrowserPluginsLocation was `/usr/lib/firefox/browser/plugins`